# IBM Cloud Object Storage nodejs authentication

Tags: node.js, get, ibm-cloud, postman, object-storage

I am trying to connect to my cloud object storage via nodejs (into node-red). I don't want to use the existing SDK. For simplicity I will use in this question postman/curl. Moreover, the following request should list all my buckets.

Here is my current curl equivalent request (created from postman)

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: s3.us-south.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud
ibm-service-instance-id: MY INSTANCE ID
Content-Type: text/plain
Authorization: Bearer MYTOKEN
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.13.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: POSTMAN TOKEN
Host: s3.us-south.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache
```

But this returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <Resource></Resource>
    <RequestId>REQ ID</RequestId>
    <httpStatusCode>403</httpStatusCode>
</Error>
```

Is there something I am missing? I am refering to this documentation:
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/cli?topic=cloud-object-storage-compatibility-api-bucket-operations#compatibility-api-list-buckets

Comment: How did you obtain the token?

Comment: @data_henrik via the service credentials tab: http://prntscr.com/o3s6mg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to obtain an API auth token. For that you need the API key which you already got. See here for [how to request the IAM access token](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-curl#curl-token). Basically:

```
curl -X "POST" "https://iam.cloud.ibm.com/identity/token" \
     -H 'Accept: application/json' \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
     --data-urlencode "apikey={api-key}" \
     --data-urlencode "response_type=cloud_iam" \
     --data-urlencode "grant_type=urn:ibm:params:oauth:grant-type:apikey"
```